# Octave: All plot label characters in Greek

Tags: escaping, octave

I'm running Octave 3.2.4 on Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.10 (squeeze).

The following code produces a plot label that is in all Greek. Whenever one symbol appears in Greek, they all do. Is this a bug or I'm I doing something wrong?

```
xlabel('Frequency, \omega (natural frequency)');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Octave 3.2.4 is really old.. I guess you have installed it with apt-get or aptitude in your debian old-stable? And yes, I think it's a bug.

I would suggest to build the current stable 3.8.2 release from source. Just get the tarball from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/, untar it, install the dependencies listed on [Compile Octave on Debian squeeze](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems#The_right_way), configure, make, make install it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider this! Actually, I had previously installed Octave 3.6.2 from backports but then uninstalled it after realizing it was incompatible with other 3.2.4 packages such as octave-plot and octave-doc.